# Рассчитать последовательность сгибов на полоске бумаги

Tags: python, list, список

Условие задачи:
На столе лежит длинная горизонтальная полоска бумаги. Её складывают вдвое, прикладывая правый в левому; и так далее. Всего такую операцию складывания повторяют i раз. После этого полоску снова разворачивают в обратном порядке. В результате на полоске остается `2^i-1` сгибов; некоторые из них направлены вверх (U), некоторые вниз (D). Необходимо вывести серию с 1-го сгиба до последнего, считая слева направо.

```
a = list("D")
```

если входное число равно i, то повторить цикл i раз.
Цикл должен добавлять на место 0 и четное по очереди D и U
То есть если число 3, тогда мы добавляем сначала выполняем чтобы получилось

```
#2 - D DU
```

А после еще добавляем на 0 и на 2 В степени i четных числа поочередно D и U

```
#3 - D DU DDUU




i = 1 - D
i = 2 - D DU
i = 3 - D DU DDUU
i = 4 - D DU DDUU DDDUUDUU
i = 5 - D DU DDUU DDDUUDUU DDDUDDUUUDDUUDUU

1<=i<=10
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно

Comment: ... "но ооочень интересно"...

Comment: Вот задача: на столе лежит длинная горизонтальная полоска бумаги. Её складывают вдвое, прикладывая правый в левому; и так далее. Всего такую операцию складывания повторяют i раз. После этого полоску сново разворачивают в обратном порядке.
     В результате на полоске остается (2 в степене i) - 1 сгибов; некоторые из них направленны вверх (U) некоторые вниз (D) необходимо вывести серию с 1-го сгиба до последнего, считая слева направо, если что не понятно спросите

Comment: @Adbe отредактируйте свой вопрос - добавьте туда условия из комментария.

Comment: Поставил минус так как: **1)** Вопрос не отражает стремления разобраться (автор не предоставил своих попыток решения и соображений). **2)** Он непонятен - есть подозрение, что автор специально не ставит оригинальное задание в вопрос, потому что шифруется от задавшего эту задачу (препод, собеседование). Комментарий же можно быстро удалить, без следов. **3)** В таком виде вопрос несёт мало пользы для кого либо, кроме автора вопроса (которому просто нужно решение), так как люди решающие подобную задачу не смогут найти её через поисковик.

Comment: Между тем, задача интересная, я её решил. Но выкладывать не буду, чтобы не приманивать сюда тучи хитрецов-халявщиков. В них мало пользы для комьюнити, больше вреда, так как они забивают главную страницу  своими низкокачественными вопросами, отвлекая внимание от действительно хороших. Если автор изменит вопрос, в соответствии с требованиями, я сделаю ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Используя метод внимательного всматривания и применяя простую логику, можно заметить, что вторая часть является зеркальным отражением первой части с инверсией. Ведь при складывании полоски пополам образуется новый сгиб вниз, а остальные сгибы на перевернутой правой половине соответствуют сгибам на левой

```
def folds(num):
    res = [0]
    for i in range(num):
        res.append(0)
        res.extend([(1-x) for x in reversed(res[:-1])])
    return res

for i in range(6):
   print(folds(i))
```

Comment: А как в этот код можно добавить инпут чтобы при заданом числе производилась выиления для данного количества сгибов, и замени нули и единицы на D и U

Comment: Надо ведь и самостоятельно что-то сделать, а?